# onChange - Testing using Jest Enzyme - check?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test onChange for the following code: using Jest / Enzyme
The test is passing but coverage does not change, any reason ?
file.js

```
      <div className='tab-input-container'>
        <select className='shape-dropdown' onChange={this.handleChange} name='category' defaultValue={!this.props.defaultData.category.$.id ? 'default' : this.props.defaultData.category.$.id}>
          {categories}
        </select>
```

file.test.js
Am I missing something? On change is being called 4 times. Here is just one example

```
it('should call the handleChange() function and change the state', () => {
  const value = 'someValue';
  wrapper.setState({
    localState: {}
  });
  wrapper.instance().handleChange('someName')({ target: { value, name } });
  expect(wrapper.state('someName')).toEqual(value);
});
```

> ERROR: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I added a `console.log` right under `handleChange` method: it is getting call because console log is returning ' SomeName'

Comment: Try adding a `jest.spyOn` on `handChange`, and `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();` to check if the method is really called.

Comment: @Zak I updated my answer, please take a look.. thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for handlechange as well?