# Enzyme is not testing onChange method

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test, by passing mock data the on change method for App.test.js, however im getting the following error.

> ● Should handle onChange event › should handle onChange event
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected)
>
> Expected value to equal:
>   "Owl"
> Received:
>   undefined
>
> Difference:
>
>   Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.
> ```

i checked out a similar post

[onChange - Testing using Jest Enzyme - check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789468/onchange-testing-using-jest-enzyme-check), however their wasn't an answer that could help

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Card from './Card';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const Styles = {
    marginTop: '100px',
    inputStyle: {
        borderRadius: '0px',
        border: 'none',
        borderBottom: '2px solid #000',
        outline: 'none',
        focus: 'none'
    }
}
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            title: undefined,
            url: undefined
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({query: e.target.value})
    }
    getGIY = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { query } = this.state;
        await fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${query}&api_key=iBXhsCDYcnktw8n3WSJvIUQCXRqVv8AP&limit=5`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.setState({
            title: data[0].title,
            url: data[0].images.downsized.url
          });
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 mx-auto" style={Styles}>
                <h1 className="gif-title">Random GIF fetch</h1>
                <form className="form-group" onSubmit={this.getGIY}>
                    <input
                        style={Styles.inputStyle}
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        name="query"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        placeholder="Search GIF..."/>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">Get GIF</button>
                </form>
                <Card title={this.state.title} url={this.state.url}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
PropTypes.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getGIY:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    title:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url:PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';


describe('Should render App Component', ()=> {
  it('should render app component', ()=> {
    const component = shallow(<App />);
  })
})

describe('Should have h1 title', ()=> {
  it('Should show Random GIF fetch', ()=>{
    const component = shallow(<App/>);

    expect(component.find("h1.gif-title")).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(component.find("h1.gif-title").text()).toContain("Random GIF fetch")
  })
})



describe('Should handle onChange event', ()=> {
  it('should handle onChange event', ()=> {
    const component = shallow(<App/>)
    const form = component.find('input')

    form.props().onChange({
      target:{
        title: 'Owl',
        query: 'Owl',
        url: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/qISaMW1xwmvNS/giphy.gif'
      }
    });
    expect(component.state('query')).toEqual('Owl')

  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler sets the state based on `e.target.value`:

```js
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({query: e.target.value})
}
```

...but you're not passing anything for `target.value` in your mocked event.

Change your test to this:

```js
describe('Should handle onChange event', ()=> {
  it('should handle onChange event', ()=> {
    const component = shallow(<App/>)
    const form = component.find('input')

    form.props().onChange({
      target:{
        value: 'Owl'
      }
    });
    expect(component.state('query')).toEqual('Owl')  // Success!
  })
})
```

...and it should work.

Comment: it worked thanks. whats the best way to test the onSubmit handler being that it deals with an api fetch ? what would be a good resource/docs/guide to check  out

Comment: You'll want to mock `fetch` on the `global` object.  I don't actually see any SO answers that show how to do that for a `React` component function.  If you want to create a new question I'll post an answer that walks you through how to do it. @randal

Comment: Ok, ill try to figure it out, and if i get stuck... i'll post a question and  just hope an answer just comes by :) thanks again.

Comment: yeah i got stuck :'(,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462069/enzyme-async-await-mock-function-not-being-called