# Enzyme async await mock function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test an async await function, however im getting an error.

> ● Should handle getGIF event › should handle getGIF event
>
> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
>
> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
> ```

I'm unsure how to test async await functions, so i was using this blog as an example https://medium.com/@rishabhsrao/mocking-and-testing-fetch-with-jest-c4d670e2e167

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Card from './Card';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const Styles = {
    marginTop: '100px',
    inputStyle: {
        borderRadius: '0px',
        border: 'none',
        borderBottom: '2px solid #000',
        outline: 'none',
        focus: 'none'
    }
}
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            title: undefined,
            url: undefined
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({query: e.target.value})
    }
    // testing this function 
    getGIY = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { query } = this.state;
        await fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${query}&api_key=iBXhsCDYcnktw8n3WSJvIUQCXRqVv8AP&limit=5`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.setState({
            title: data[0].title,
            url: data[0].images.downsized.url
          });
        })
        .catch( (err) =>{
            console.log(err)
        });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 mx-auto" style={Styles}>
                <h1 className="gif-title">Random GIF fetch</h1>
                <form className="form-group" onSubmit={this.getGIY}>
                    <input
                        style={Styles.inputStyle}
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.query}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        placeholder="Search GIF..."/>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">Get GIF</button>
                </form>
                <Card title={this.state.title} url={this.state.url}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
PropTypes.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getGIY:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    title:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url:PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';



describe('Should handle getGIF event', ()=> {
  it('should handle getGIF event', done => {
    const component = shallow(<App/>)

    const mockSuccessResponse = {};
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockSuccessResponse);
    const mockQuery = "Owl"

    const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
      json:() => mockJsonPromise,

    });
    jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(()=> mockFetchPromise);

    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${mockQuery}&api_key=iBXhsCDYcnktw8n3WSJvIUQCXRqVv8AP&limit=5`);

    process.nextTick(() => { // 6
      expect(component.state()).toEqual({
        // ... assert the set state
      });

      global.fetch.mockClear(); // 7
      done(); // 8
    });

  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

describe('Should handle getGIF event', () => {

  let mock, actualFetch;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mock = jest.fn();
    actualFetch = global.fetch;
    global.fetch = mock;
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    global.fetch = actualFetch;
  });

  it('should handle getGIF event', async () => {
    const component = shallow(<App />);
    component.setState({ query: 'Owl' });
    mock.mockResolvedValue({ 
      json: () => Promise.resolve({
        data: [{
          title: 'the title',
          images: { downsized: { url: 'the url' }}
        }]
      })
    });
    const form = component.find('form');

    await form.props().onSubmit({ preventDefault: () => {} });

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=Owl&api_key=iBXhsCDYcnktw8n3WSJvIUQCXRqVv8AP&limit=5');  // Success!
    expect(component.state('title')).toBe('the title');  // Success!
    expect(component.state('url')).toBe('the url');  // Success!
  });
});
```

---

**Details**

`fetch` might not be defined in a Node.js environment so just grabbing whatever it was and replacing it with a mock, then restoring whatever it was is a good approach.

Use [`.setState`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.html) to set the component state.

Use [`.find`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) to get the `form` and use [`.props`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html) to access its props and call its `onSubmit` function.

Use an `async` test function and `await` the `Promise` returned by `onSubmit` so it is completely done before continuing.

Use [`.state`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/state.html) to query the component state.

Comment: thanks this worked, im going to study this a bit more in depth. Whats the purpose behind beforeEach and afterEach what would happen if you didn't use them ?

Comment: `beforeEach` and `afterEach` **always** run before and after a test so it's safer to do mocking (especially `global` mocking) within them.  (If the global `fetch` is restored at the end of the test, but the test fails and doesn't run to the end, then `fetch` will still be mocked afterwards). @randal

Comment: I see, where would be best place to learn more about unit testing react components or apps ? any docs or blogs you would recommend ? Thanks again for this. I learn better from my mistakes/failures.

Comment: FYI, I just improved the test a little by using `find` and `props` to call the `onSubmit` property of the `form`. @randal

Comment: As far as docs go, the `Jest` and `Enzyme` docs are pretty good for discovering the toolset available.  They are both continuously being enhanced so it's good to watch the changelogs for the latest enhancements.  The answers here on SO are a pretty good resource, they usually follow best practices.  @randal

Comment: Thank alot brian this helps out alot.  :)